# Discord.py deleting every channel in a server

Tags: python, discord.py

im working on a building discord bot in py and im wondering how to delete every channel. Someone help?

Comment: What packages are you using, there are several wrappers out there and what have you tried so far? You should at least give it a go before posting a question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't abuse this.**

```py
@bot.command()
async def delchannels(ctx):
    for c in ctx.guild.channels: # iterating through each guild channel
        await c.delete()
```

You can also vary this specifically for text channels or voice channels using the links from the references.

Note that you can also use a `try`/`except` if you wish to pass the channels that the bot doesn't have permissions to delete.

Consider this less destructive command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def delchannel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await channel.delete()
```

And alter the argument type for specific channel types (`VoiceChannel`, `CategoryChannel`).

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.channels)
- [`Guild.voice_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_channels)
- [`Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.text_channels)
- [`GuildChannel.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.delete)